# MVC5 Route To Null Area Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am working with a default MVC5 Web application with the Web Api 'extension'. The solution comes with a 'web' Account controller, 'web' Home controller, a 'api' Values controller as well as a Help area with its own controller. The help controller details my api in html.

This is all default.

My issue is when I am in the Help area some of my action links (on the top menu) do not work. I expected the action on the top menu (Login, ect) to return to the default non-area routes, they did not. They instead redirected to the Help area. The "Application Name" that navigates to root works but Contact,About,Login,Register (ext) do not.

I have tried changing the action links to point to 'null' area, but that does not help.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)
```

The Action Links do not have the correct URI when I am within the Help area. When I mouse over the home action link it redirects me to localhost:port/Help. I would Like the action links to redirect back to the default controller routes (No area, Home/Account controller).

**LoginPartial**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink", area = "" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", area = "" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by not working? i.e. 404, wrong view rendered, etc...

Comment: Sure. The Action Links do not have the correct URI when I am within the Help area. When I mouse over the home action link it redirects me to localhost:port/Help. I would Like the action links to redirect back to the default controller routes (No area, Home/Account controller).

Comment: Are you rendering the menu from a shared partial in the root `/views/` folder by any chance?

Comment: @BrentMannering Yes I am. Both the LoginPartial and Layout are located in the shared folder.

Comment: Could you post the code for the LoginPartial (assuming this is where the problem links are)?

Comment: @BrentMannering Added above. The error occurs also in the Layout root. Moreover I have tried to explicitly set the area (area="") in the route values without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can identify as the possible culprit in the `LoginPartial` is the `area` property set in the `htmlAttributes` not the `routeValues`. However I'm guessing this could have been from trying different things.

Modifying the `routeValues` seems to be working for me though:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: new { area = "" }, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: new { area = "" }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: new { area = "" }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```